# Trigonometry explanation

Tags: trigonometry

Determine a value for $\sec (1/\sqrt2)$.

Explain the difference between $\sec (1/\sqrt2)$ and $\cos^{-1} (1/\sqrt2)$, for the explanation can you relate it to the graphs of functions?

This is a simple question but for some reason when I do $\sec (1/\sqrt2)$ I get the wrong awnser? I did $\cos(\sqrt2)$and kept calculator in degree mode.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\sec\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right) = \frac{1}{\cos \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right)}
$$
which means to find the cosine of the angle of $1/\sqrt{2}$ radians, and take it's multiplicative inverse. This yields approximately $0.7602446$.

The other one is
$$
\cos^{-1} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right)
 = \arccos \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right),
$$
the measure of the angle, whose cosine would be $1/\sqrt{2}$ radians. This would be the $45^\circ$ angle, which is $\pi/4 \approx 0.7854$ radians